# Cannot found org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base32() from matlab

Tags: java, apache, matlab

I've tried to import the following code in `MatLab` and it works:

```
encoder = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64();
```

While this code does not work:

```
encoder = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base32();
```

Anyone know why? Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you know it does not work?

Comment: Wich version of apache codec you use. Base32 is since version 1.5

Comment: I got this error message:

Comment: Undefined variable "org" or class "org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base32".

Comment: I also tried import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64; and it works. But import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base32; returns an error says Import argument 'org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base32' cannot be found or
cannot be imported.

Answer (score -1):

I think I got the answer: we can only run Base32 after we import the class to matlab.

Base64's description says "Creates a Base64 codec used for decoding (all modes) and encoding in URL-unsafe mode", while Base32's description is "Creates a Base32 codec used for decoding and encoding" which doesn't say it support URL.

Anyway, I downloaded the package and imported to matlab and works. Thanks guys